# Can we build phonegap in QNX momentics IDE for blackberry 10?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

Can we build phonegap in QNX momentics IDE for blackberry 10 like [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)